# Custom NSValueTransformer in xcode 6 with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nsvaluetransformer

Did anyone successfully implement a custom NSValueTransformer in xcode 6 beta with swift?

I have the following swift class:

```
import Foundation

class myTransformer: NSValueTransformer {

  let amount = 100

  override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass!
  {
    return NSNumber.self
  }

  override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! {
    return value.integerValue + amount
  }
}
```

So all this transformer should do is, adding 100 to a given value in the gui.

As you can see, the transformer class appears now in the Value Transformer drop down in IB.

[image]

But if I choose this transformer the application crashes with:

```
2014-08-27 20:12:17.686 cdTest[44134:303] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Cannot find value transformer with name newTransformer'
```

Is it right to register this transformer in the AppDelegate with

```
override class func initialize() {
  let newTransformer = myTransformer()
}
```

Does anyone know how this whole stuff should work?

kind regards!
martin

Comment: I would guess that it's the swift name mangling. Try declaring it with @objc to get around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you initialise **newTransformer** you should also include the line:

```
NSValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(newTransformer, forName: "myTransformer")
```

Then in your Interface Builder you should use **myTransformer** instead of **newTransformer** under the Value Transformer dropdown.

Comment: This is not the best answer.

Answer (score 41):

From Xcode release notes:

> If you set a Swift subclass of NSValueTransformer as a binding’s value
>   transformer, the XIB or storyboard will contain an invalid reference
>   to the class, and the binding will not work properly at runtime. You
>   can either enter a mangled class name into the Value Transformer field
>   or add the @objc(…) attribute to the NSValueTransformer subclass to
>   solve this problem. (17495784)

From Swift guide:

> To make your Swift class accessible and usable back in Objective-C,
>   make it a descendant of an Objective-C class or mark it with the @objc
>   attribute. To specify a particular name for the class to use in
>   Objective-C, mark it with @objc(<#name#>), where <#name#> is the name
>   that your Objective-C code will use to reference the Swift class. For
>   more information on @objc, see Swift Type Compatibility.

Solution:

Declare your class as `@objc(myTransformer) class myTransformer: NSValueTransformer` and then you can use "myTransformer" as name...

Comment: This fixed everything for me. Another great resource that helped—the NSHipster article on NSValueTransformer: http://nshipster.com/nsvaluetransformer/

Comment: Thank you for perfect answer!

Comment: I was just about to up vote this and realised I had already sometime in the past. ++2

Comment: thank you! A pity this is not the one marked as the answer!