# Exception while running ibtool: Cannot find value transformer with name

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode8, nsvaluetransformer

I just upgraded Xcode to 8.0 (8A218a) and am converting my project in Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0. The only issue left now is this error:

> "Exception while running ibtool: Cannot find value transformer with
>   name UTIToIconTransformer"

The `UTIToIconTransformer` is defined something like:

```
@objc(UTIToIconTransformer) class UTIToIconTransformer : ValueTransformer {
    // ...
}
```

The code worked fine when it was in Swift 2.3. The binding using this value transformer is set like this:

[image]

If I remove this binding, the app runs, and the row titles are shown correctly.

I have tried calling `NSValueTransformer.setValueTransformer()` in the app delegate's `+initialize()`, in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and in the value transformer's `+initialize()`, as suggested [here](http://bluelemonbits.com/index.php/2016/02/07/using-nsvaluetransformers-value-transformer-swift-2-0/), [here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534334/custom-nsvaluetransformer-in-xcode-6-with-swift) and [here at NShipster](http://nshipster.com/nsvaluetransformer/) (Though I don't think the statement of "Typically, the singleton instance would be registered in the +initialize method of the value transformer subclass, so it could be used without further setup." complies with the Apple's doc.), all without success.

In the [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/Registration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002166-BAJEAIEE), it says

```
Value transformers are typically registered by an application’s delegate 
class, in response to receiving a initialize: class message. This allows 
registration to occur early in the application startup process, providing
access to the value transformers as nib files load.

Availability in Interface Builder

Your NSValueTransformer subclasses are not automatically listed in the
Interface Builder bindings inspector. When inspecting a binding you can enter
the name that the value transformer is registered with, but the functionality 
will not be present in Interface Builder’s test mode. When your application 
is compiled and run the transformer will be used.
```

But registering in the `AppDelegate`'s `override class func initialize()` didn't help. In Xcode 7 and Swift 2.3, it even worked without the registration.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by removing the `NSOutlineView` from the storyboard and setting up a new one.
I have another project which also has an outlineview binded with an `NSTreeController`, and that project has no problem after the Xcode 8.0 upgrade. Then I tried creating a new `ValueTransformer` with a new name, with no luck.
I guess there may be something wrong with the storyboard, so I tried recreating the outline view. Then Xcode doesn't complain that it can't find the transformers!